# Numpy loadtxt remove leading zeros (convert) and define spaces delimiter

Tags: python, numpy, converters

I have files with XYZ coordinates generated by some software in the way of fixed column widths including spaces and leading zeros:

```
00666666.66     07777777.77     0000333.33
```

Using line:

```
data = np.loadtxt(input_xyz, delimiter = " ", skiprows = 0, unpack = True)
```

Update: Thanks to the answer below I realized leading zeros are not the issue with numpy.loadtxt - it automatically strip them off. In this case my problem is how to specify delimiter () when there is minimum 1 space or more between values. I found out without specifying delimiter it works aromatically, but I have a reason why I must specify it.

Comment: It's been mentioned before - `loadtxt` accepts in iterable, including a generator.  So you can create a function that reads a line, massages it, and passes it on to `loadtxt`.

Comment: It just occurred to me that `np.genfromtxt` accepts of a list of field widths as the `delimiter`.  The could be an alternative to the default white spaces delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my quick test the leading 0s don't give a problem:

```
In [442]: np.loadtxt([b'00666666.66     07777777.77     0000333.33'])
Out[442]: array([  6.66666660e+05,   7.77777777e+06,   3.33330000e+02])
```

It produces an array of floats.

This string, with the default `split` produces

```
In [446]: b'00666666.66     07777777.77     0000333.33'.split()
Out[446]: [b'00666666.66', b'07777777.77', b'0000333.33']
```

With one blank space:

```
In [448]: b'00666666.66     07777777.77     0000333.33'.split(b' ')
Out[448]: 
[b'00666666.66',
 b'',
 b'',
 b'',
 b'',
 b'07777777.77',
 b'',
 b'',
 b'',
 b'',
 b'0000333.33']
```

It's one of those empty strings that's producing the error: `b''`

Is this, by any chance, tab delimited?

Comment: I just checked with small sample and you are right. It is defining the delimiter which is causing the troubles. I can't omit the delimiter definition, going to update the question...

Comment: In my test `split` with ' ', produces a lot of empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove leading zeros, but must be careful of various situations:

```
>>> import re
>>> input_xyz = '0012.0034  00000000  00000.12  -012.0034'
>>> re.sub(r'(?m)(^[+-]?|\s+[+-]?)(0(?=\d))+', r'\1', input_xyz)
'12.0034  0  0.12  -12.0034'
```